# Disabling Rails logging from script/runner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

Is there some way to disable all logging (whether from ActiveRecord, other parts of Rails, plugins, etc.) from a script running via `script/runner`? I've got a long data-loading script running, and it's generating an absurd amount of useless logging information. I'm *not* trying to change `script/runner`'s environment (e.g., production, development, etc.)- the script currently needs to run in the "development" environment, and it's doing so without issue at the moment.

All I want to do is suppress all logging for the duration of the script's lifetime. From reading the docs, it looks like if I can get a handle to its `Rails::Configuration` I should be either able to set `log_level` to something other than `:debug` or set its `logger` to `nil`. Am I on the right track? If so, how do I get access to its `Rails::Configuration` object?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are a couple of ways I can think of.

1) Set the log level so high that nothing will get logged:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::Severity::UNKNOWN
```

See [Logger::Severity](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/logger/rdoc/classes/Logger/Severity.html) for more about that. UNKNOWN is the highest.

"level" is just a number, so it can be set to Logger::Severity::UNKNOWN + 1 if you feel paranoid. :)

2) Send the output to /dev/null.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new('/dev/null')
```

(I'm assuming that there is just one instance of Logger that is used by Rails, and that it's the one you get via ActiveRecord::Base.logger. If there are more of them you'd have to find them and fiddle with them also.)

If you don't like these you might find something else by reading the [Logger](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/logger/rdoc/) docs.

Comment: I put ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::Severity::UNKNOWN at the end of enviroment.rb and that works. (doing config.log_level = :info doesn't seem to work with mongrel)

Comment: `Logger::Severity::UNKNOWN + 1` is very funny! =)

Answer (score 0):

The settings are in your config/environments/*.rb files, which override the default for  environment.rb. When it does "Rails::Initializer.run do |config|" it's running with the config object. I'm fairly sure you can change either to suite your needs, but I'm not sure how you'd pass it a flag saying it was a script/runner script currently executing.

(I know you said your not interested in changing the environment, but I thought I'd throw out there that you could [create a new env](http://glu.ttono.us/articles/2006/05/22/guide-environments-in-rails-1-1) for a dataload script that has most of the same settings but no logging fairly easily)

Comment: Huh. That's a decent idea, maybe I'll give that a try.

But, as far as you know, there's no way to override configuration settings on the fly?

Comment: I'm not aware of any; after environment runs, I'm not even sure if you can access the values that were set.